# AWS vmimport - stuck on booting phase

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services

Currently importing an OVA from an S3 bucket. Windows 2008 R2 Standard

Process stops at the booting phase

"StatusMessage": "FirstBootFailure: This import request failed because the instance failed to boot and establish network connectivity.",

This is a single volume machine that boots up fine if the OVA is reimported back to VMware.

There is a logon disclaimer box configured to appear before choosing the account to logon to.

I've followed the AWS VMimport pre-reqs, It is not domain joined, AV disabled, Windows Updates set to manual.

A similar OVA has imported fine, so struggling to understand what is different about this one.

Anyone able to offer a view on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all the Windows image import pre-requisites @ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html?

Most notably: available disk space, NIC configuration (single NIC, IPV4, DHCP), Windows license (could you be hitting the Windows sysprep limit or similar issues), possible WMware-attached ISO images.

Answer (score 0):

For reference this was due to an overly secure firewall being configured. Disabling the firewall, which was not originally possible, solved this.